# Roll back previous state after execute command ubuntu

Tags: command-line

How i cancel the effects then execute a any command(like a make directorys, install package etc) in terminal? its posible?

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it seems like you want a general "undo" feature for the operating system. Such a feature does not exist. However, if you happen to be running Ubuntu within a virtual machine, most virtualization software allows you to take snapshots and then revert to an earlier snapshot if something goes wrong.

Otherwise, the best you can do is make sure you make frequent backups, know what you are doing, and test out commands in a safe environment (such as a VM or a normal user) before you run them in your production environment. For simple commands like  installing packages, you can of course just remove the package (`apt-get remove <package_name>`), but all of those would be on a case-by-case basis of course. Not every simple command has a simple "undo".